# Cannot display ArrayList

Tags: java

I am doing a heavy operation with arrayList of arrayLists. when I am trying to display the parent array list, I have a problem that it's displaying empty arraylists as below

My arrayList declaration is hereunder

```
List<List<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Here is my child list

```
List<String> stringLine = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In my program I am adding this stringLine to arrayList like this

```
arrayList.add(stringLine);
```

My output when trying to print parent arrayList
printing size of arrayList so far 44 content is : `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`

Note: In the above output 44 is the no of arrayList elements it has

When I try to print the child it displays good

```
StringLine is : [1640, 1138, 878, 1600, 1978, 280, 24, 2509, 702, 553, 2362, 2019, 1558, 2494, 823, 35, 1181, 1915, 1261, 1448, 493, 798, 1160, 651, 2249, 1639, 2428, 458, 2556, 939, 2114, 2339, 2373, 286, 2078, 844, 2673, 1486, 1657, 1531, 1043, 734, 2247, 2121, 75, 2599, 975, 29, 175, 960, 2151, 480, 868, 2627, 1941, 671, 2529, 1952, 1623, 2160, 2298]
```

Where, I was wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my code snippet, where in I am adding a list to the parent arrayList

```
private void splitString(String temp) {
    System.out.println("In splitString method..");
    List<String> stringLine = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(temp, " ");
    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        stringLine.add(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
    }
    if (stringLine.size() != 3) {
        arrayList.add(stringLine);
    }
    stringLine.clear();
}
```

Comment: Are you just calling ToString on the parent list, or are you iterating it and calling toString on each child?

Comment: In other words, are you just printing `System.out.println(arrayList)`?

Comment: Can you post the code that loops through the parent array list and prints the child lists?

Comment: @WChargin Yes, I did the same System.out.println(arrayList).

Comment: -1 `stringLine.clear()` hence the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

After posting your code, the error is obvious. As you can see here [List#clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) will remove all the elements in your `List`. Since you are intentionally removing them, it should come as no surprise the output is empty.

Remove this line: `stringLine.clear();` and everything should be fine. You are passing the `List<String>` by reference with `arrayList.add`, which means it will still point to the same `stringLine` you are clearing. If you really need to clear you need to deep-clone.

You need to nest the `for in` loops properly and everything will work fine:

```
List<List<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> stringLine = new ArrayList<String>();
stringLine.add("5");
stringLine.add("7");
arrayList.add(stringLine);
for (List<String> list : arrayList) {// each list in the arrayList
    for (String current : list) {// each element in each list
        System.out.println(current);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to print an entire `List` at once:

```
for (List<String> list : arrayList) {// each list in the arrayList
    System.out.println(list); // will work as expected.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which means at the end you are clearing all elements from `stringLine`. The following is the test case

```
List<List<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> stringLine = new ArrayList<String>();
stringLine.add("1");
stringLine.add("2");
List<String> stringLine1 = new ArrayList<String>();
stringLine1.add("3");
stringLine1.add("4");
arrayList.add(stringLine);
arrayList.add(stringLine1);
stringLine1.clear(); // check this
stringLine.clear(); 
System.out.println(arrayList);
```

output : `[[], []]`

Comment: am amazed to see so many upvotes for this question..+1 for the correct ans..You should also ans why it is that way so that op can understand where he was going wrong

Comment: @Anirudh :-) yes, simple to fix. I'd answered for original questions without any code later the questioner's made changes in his question.

Answer (score 1):

Even though people have answered this already they haven't explained why this happens.

Java has references to values just like C / C++. So when you create a new ArrayList() it'll create a NEW ArrayList for you somewhere in memory. But if you use the `=` operator and assign it to another variable, it'll just point to that location in memory.

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
ArrayList b = a; //Both a and b point to the same thing here.
```

From this point forwards, adding or deleting elements to a is the same as adding or deleting to b. Since you are using the same ArrayList at the same memory location for all your operations when you clear() the ArrayList in the end, everything gets cleared.

An easy way to notice what your code is doing is to simply print out while you are adding things to your ArrayList of ArrayLists.

```
private void splitString(String temp) {
    System.out.println("In splitString method..");
    List stringLine = new ArrayList();
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(temp, " ");
    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        stringLine.add(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
    }
    if (stringLine.size() != 3) {
        arrayList.add(stringLine);
        System.out.println(arrayList); //DEBUG LINE HERE
    }
    stringLine.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming stringLine is a String[]. Therefore you either need to do an array loop (as in @alex23's answer) or use [CollectionUtils#addAll](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) like:

```
CollectionUtils.addAll(arrayList, stringLine);
```